# integrate IMAP on php website

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to integrate IMAP on website, but i am stuck in the first itself. I am not able to establish the connection. The code that I used was:

```
$connect_to = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
//$connect_to =  '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX'; tried this method also
$user = 'abc@gmail.com';
$password = 'abc123';

$connection = imap_open($connect_to, $user, $password)
  or die("Can't connect to '$connect_to': " . imap_last_error());

imap_close($connection);
```

I checked the firewall, authentication from gmail, allowed less secure app from gmail end, but everytime i am getting this error

```
Can't connect to '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX': Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/account
```

Can anyone please tell why this is happening and how can i rectify it. I also would like to know is there a way where i can allow all web mails together, currently its only for gmail but i would like it to work for all server such as yahoo, hotmail, aol etc

Comment: Did you check https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2984937 ?

Comment: does connection succeeds when you use yahoo credentials ?

Comment: @Jitendra Purohit currently i have coded for gmail, so i am using gmail account havnt tested with yahoo

Comment: @Ken Van Hoeylandt yes and i have done as they have said

Comment: have you tried https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha ?